# Как передать в метод Vue js, ссылку на переменную из data?

Tags: vue.js

Есть существует большое количество переменных в data.
Я хочу при клике на кнопку отнимать 1, от текущей переменной. Но с некоторыми условиями которые я пропишу в методе. Как мне передать ССЫЛКУ на переменную в метод? Чтобы не создавать кучу методов.

Comment: доступ к переменным в `data` осуществляется через `this`. Например, `this.count = 1`

Comment: через `this` я обращаюсь к ним в самом методе, а я хочу в сам метод передавать разные переменные из самого шаблона. По типу <button @click="increment(val1)">Incr</button>

Comment: из шаблона  - без `this`. Именно так, как Вы написали

Comment: если я передаю без `this` передается само значение переменной, и уже определить что инкрементировать не понятно.

Comment: примитивы не передаются по ссылке. Поместите переменную в объект - и передавайте его

Comment: так дело в том что они в объекте. calc: { val1: 0, val2: 0, val3: 0 }

Answer (score 0):

Передавай переменную в кавычках (как строку). Вот так:

```
<button @click="increment( 'val1' )">Incr</button>
```

А в методе обращайся как к элементу массива:

```
fnc1(el) {
     this.calc[el];
}
```